# Processing pairs of successive elements in a list with standard mapping functions?

Tags: functional-programming, lisp, common-lisp

I have a small exercise in Lisp:

> Write a function `test-delta` with parameters `delta` and `lst`, which will
>   check if the difference between successive elements in `lst` is smaller than
>   `delta`. Write the function in two ways:
>
> - recursively
> - using a mapping function

I have no problem writing that function recursively, but I don't know which mapping function I should use.  All the standard mapping functions work with only one element of the list at a time. `reduce` cannot be used either, because I do not have some operation to use between successive elements.   What function *could* I use here?

Comment: You *can* use reduce here, but it's probably easier to use `(mapcar fn lst (rest lst))`, since `mapcar` can work with *multiple* lists.  This gives you an easy way to use a binary predicate on each element and its successor.  Even better, since it incorporates most of the logic that you need, is to use the `every` function, which can also take multiple lists.  Then you just have `(every diff-less-than-delta lst (rest lst))`.  I've added [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23916891/1281433).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> All standard functions are working only with one element at time.
>
> Reduce function cannot be use either
>   because i do not have some operation to use between to elements.

There's already [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23906689/1281433) by uselpa showing that you can do this with `reduce`, but it feels a bit awkward to me to bend `reduce` to this case.

It's much more natural, in my opinion, to recognize that the standard mapping functions actually let you work with multiple lists.  I'll show `mapcar` and `loop` first, and then `every`, which I think is the real winner here.  Finally, just for completeness, I've also included `maplist`.

### mapcar

The standard `mapcar` can take more than one list, which means that you can take elements from two different lists at once.  Of particular note, it could take a `list` and `(rest list)`.  E.g.,

```
(let ((list '(1 2 3 4 5 6)))
  (mapcar 'cons
          list
          (rest list)))

;=> ((1 . 2) (2 . 3) (3 . 4) (4 . 5) (5 . 6))
```

### loop

You can use `loop` to do the same sort of thing:

```
(loop
   with l = '(1 2 3 4 5 6)
   for a in l
   for b in (rest l)
   collect (cons a b))
;=> ((1 . 2) (2 . 3) (3 . 4) (4 . 5) (5 . 6))
```

There are some other variations on `loop` that you can use, but some of them have less conventient results.  E.g., you could loop for `(a b) on list`, but then you get a (perhaps) unexpected final binding of your variables:

```
(loop for (a b) on '(1 2 3 4 5 6)
     collect (list a b))
;=> ((1 2) (2 3) (3 4) (4 5) (5 6) (6 NIL))
```

This is similar to what `maplist` will give you.

### every

I think the real winners here, though, are going to the be [`every`, `some`, `notevery`, and `notany`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_everyc.htm) functions.  These, like `mapcar` can take more than one list as an argument.  This means that your problem can simply be:

```
(let ((delta 4)
      (lst '(1 2 4 7 9)))
  (every (lambda (x y)
           (< (abs (- x y)) delta))
         lst
         (rest lst)))
;=> T

(let ((delta 2)
      (lst '(1 2 4 7 9)))
  (every (lambda (x y)
           (< (abs (- x y)) delta))
         lst
         (rest lst)))
;=> NIL
```

### maplist

You could also do this with `maplist`, which works on successive *tails* of the list, which means you'd have access to each element and the one following.  This has the same `6 NIL` at the end that the second `loop` solution did, though.  E.g.:

```
(maplist (lambda (tail)
           (list (first tail) 
                 (second tail)))
         '(1 2 3 4 5 6))
;=> ((1 2) (2 3) (3 4) (4 5) (5 6) (6 NIL))
```

Answer (score 1):

`reduce` *can* be used:

```
(defun testdelta (delta lst)
  (reduce
   (lambda (r e)
     (if (< (abs (- r e)) delta)
       e
       (return-from testdelta nil)))
   lst)
  t)
```

or, without `return-from` (but possibly slower):

```
(defun testdelta (delta lst)
  (and
   (reduce
    (lambda (r e) 
      (and r (if (< (abs (- r e)) delta) e nil)))
    lst)
   t))
```

Comment: Hmm, nice. Thanks, i didnt wanna use return from